# How do I retrieve and use a "trigger_id" with Slack API?

Tags: c#, slack-api

I want to make it possible for my SlackApp to use the following method:

[`apps.permissions.request`](https://api.slack.com/methods/apps.permissions.request)

this method requires the attribute "trigger_id" to be sent with the request. 
So I looked it up in the documentation for the Slack API. It says I can receive a `trigger_id` from three things:

- Slash command executions
- Message button clicks
- Message menu selections

The Problem is, that all three methods require a URL that it can send an answer to - I would need a server for this, and this is out of the question!

Isn't there any other way to receive a `trigger_id`, or more directly, is there another way to set / request new scopes for my app than `apps.permissions.request` - besides just setting the scopes in the menu for the app directly?

Answer (score 1):

### Trigger ID

No. The only way for your app to get a valid trigger ID are the methods your mentioned. All of them require your app to be able to receive a request from Slack. Most Slack apps are therefore running on a webserver / in the cloud so they can fully use these features.

### Workspace apps

The method [`apps.permissions.request`](https://api.slack.com/methods/apps.permissions.request) is part of a new type of apps called "workspace apps", which require a special type of token called "workspace tokens".

Please note that Slack announced that workspace apps will not be developed further are now considered legacy. All related methods are only guaranteed to work until October 2019 and I would in general not recommend to use them at all. See the articles [Legacy: Workspace apps](https://api.slack.com/legacy-workspace-apps) and [An Update on Workspace Apps](https://medium.com/slack-developer-blog/an-update-on-workspace-apps-aabc9e42a98b) for more information about workspace apps.

### Changing scopes programmatically

You can not change the scope of your app programmatically with a regular Slack app.

But there is another way that might solve your problem:

Your app can programmatically request a subset of all scopes defined for your Slack app in the OAuth process. So for example if your app is configured to use scopes A, B, C, one user could request a token with scopes A only. And another could request a token with scopes B, C only, etc.

Comment: Hey Erik, thank you very much! The problem is that I wanted to write code that makes it possible to set scopes for each new Workspace app.
But reading now that all of this is only supported until Oct. 2019... Am I missing something? Is there another way to communicate with Slack? Do I not need an workspace app? Is there another way? I'm confused...

Comment: Hey Fabian! Workspace apps have never been fully released and will be replaced by something else next year. My recommendation is: don't use them, its a waste of time. Build a normal Slack app instead.

Comment: Workspace apps was a new approach with the goal to give apps much more granular control on scopes and rights, e.g. you can install apps into a channel instead of the whole workspace and add/remove scopes programmatically. But again, I would not use it.

Comment: Hey Erik, I don't get it. What exactly is a "normal Slack app"? I started all of this with reading the documentation for the slack api online. And it says everywhere that I first have to create a app... is this a workspace app now or a normal app??? Sorry for these questions but I am very confused right now. I allways thought my app is a workspace app - maybe it isn't?! 
Does a normal app communicate differently? No tokens? Different methods? You just threw me off the track with this answer...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. AFAIK its actually no longer possible to create workspace apps and only as part of the "developer preview" for this new feature, which ended in October 2018. So unless you did not explicitly create a workspace app back in October you have a normal Slack app.

Comment: So you should be fine. Just ignore all API methods that *only* require a workspace token. Those will not work with your standard Slack app. All of those API methods will also have special note like "Developer preview has ended", so there are easy to identify.

Comment: Ah okay, this clears a few things up. So, yeah I think I have a normal app. But now seeing that it seems like there is no way arround setting up an URL which can receive answers from Slack... I'll have to talk to my boss. This sucks, in the end it allways, at some point, comes down to needing an URL for Slack. Otherwise one misses out on crucial functions of the API.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185558/discussion-between-erik-kalkoken-and-fabian-held).